# How to fool Akamai and other CDN?

Tags: networking, dns, cdn

Seems like CDN's are configured like all Russia is Europe and it gives servers from Europe, but east part of country has better connection with Japan.

I want to trick CDN's to think that i am from Japan, so that gives me Japan servers.

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question? And take a look at this: https://www.cloudflare.com/features-cdn

Comment: I did some experiments and found that all CDN's think that best node for me in Europe, but i know that it is in Japan. How to use Japan nodes of CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine it will depend on the VPN.  The 2 most likely things a CDN is looking at for how to direct your traffic are

(1) Your IP address  and 
(2) The nameserver you are using.   This is the more likely of the 2.

If the problem is the nameserver, try finding and forcing a nameserver from Japan.   If the problem is your IP address, try changing your IP address (not trivial, the typical way to do this would be via a VPN or proxy server from the country you are wanting to appear from, ie Japan).

Also note that CDN's don't always act in what they think is the users best interest.  They sometimes act in the interest of the provider, depending on the providers capacity and rules.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could use a VPN service with servers in Japan.  This way your traffic actually goes to Japan, and the servers will treat you as being there.

I will not recommend a VPN service, but they are out there and not too expensive.

As a bonus, if your chosen service has servers around the world, then you can choose which country you want to be located in.  This can be very useful when accessing content that is only available in certain countries.